# How to append arguments to functions as you pass them along in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, chaining

This has to have been answered before, but I cant find the answer, maybe Im not searching for it properly. If it's a duplicate, please let me know.

In node, Im emitting events like so:

```
EventEmitter.emit('eventname', params)
```

Simple enough. Im listening like so

```
EventEmitter.on('eventname', doSomething)
```

Then I have my listening function doSomething

```
doSomething(params){
    // Do cool stuff
}
```

I would like to append eventEmitter class to the arguments, so I can emit additional events once the logic in doSomething has been complete. I can do it like this:

```
EventEmitter.on('eventname', params => {
    doSomething(params, EventEmitter)
})
```

But Id like to keep it all on one line.  It's more readable, and easier to scan the file to see the event and the action.  Any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to keep everything in one line, you can just remove the curly braces: `EventEmitter.on('eventname', params => doSomething(params, EventEmitter));`. Don't see the point of passing on the EventEmitter class though...

Comment: This is the only way that I see you can do it. To make it a little more compact, you could use the es6 arrow notation functions (params)=>doSomething(params, EventEmitter) or use function.bind. But then you may have to make EventEmitter the first parameter in your function.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is assign functions to variables, so its easier to call them

Something like

```
EventEmitter.emit('eventname', params)
doSomething(params){
  // Do cool stuff 
}
const anotherEvent = EventEmitter.on('anothereventname', 'anotherparams')
EventEmitter.on('eventname', params => {
  doSomething(params, anotherEvent)
})
```

Then you call place the emit wherever you want

Comment: Passing around the EventEmitter class works as I need it, I was specifically referring to the formatting of keeping the code on one line.  Thanks though.